# Are supports for spot lights required?

Tags: lighting, outdoor

If I am planning to install [this spot light](http://www.homedepot.ca/product/12v-20-watt-polyresin-rock-flood-light/914419) on the ground (in dirt), are support beams or things like that required or can I just place this in the dirt and it would be fine?

[image: Spot light]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of outdoor light comes with a stake or something to stabilize it.  I have ran a lot myself and basically I have two rules.  Run all of your wiring through PVC all the way up to fixture.  Second, if it doesn't come with something make your own stake.  If this thing is just a rock with wiring sticking out I would get some thick wiring, glue it on the bottom and stick that in the ground like a fork.  For more traditional type of lighting we put half cages over them but since this was made to look like a rock that would probably kill the aesthetics.

Answer (score -1):

I have put the lights on the ground.  I buried the wires in mulch being sure NOT to bury any connections.

Comment: This just says what you did, but doesn't provide any evidence that it was the correct thing to do. For example, including the model number of your lights and an excerpt from their installation instructions showing this mounting method.